# Updating an indirect dependency in shrinkwrapped project

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, lockfile, npm-shrinkwrap

Is there a good way with npm (I'm on `npm@5`) to do a version bump for a nested dependency in a shrinkwrapped/lockfiled project?

Doing an `npm install package@latest --save` will update the shrinkwrap file as expected, but it also adds the dependency to `package.json`, which is not what I want. Doing an `npm install --no-save package@latest` will properly skip updating `package.json`, but it also won't update the shrinkwrap file.

Is there a simple way to update the sub-dependency and shrinkwrap file without touching `package.json`?

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I most often use is a two-step process:

```
npm i --no-save subdependency@latest && npm shrinkwrap --dev
```

This is not ideal, but it works. Hopefully someone else has a one-step solution.

**Update**:

Nowadays, I do this:

```
npm i --save subdependency@latest && npm uninstall --save subdependency
```

...which is also annoying.